# Handlebars partial in Sammy.js

Tags: javascript, html, templates, handlebars.js, sammy.js

I've been scouring the docs for sammy.js and handlebars for a good amount of time, and I cannot for the life of me, determine where in http://sammyjs.org/docs/api/0.7.1/all#Sammy.Handlebars (example #2) mypartial.hb is instructed load into {{>hello_friend}}. Ideas?

Comment: where/how is that partial made inside the .hb file?

Comment: yes, sure. How can that be implemented in Sammy

Answer (score 0):

i this question is old but for all sammyjs lover

```
var app = $.sammy('#app', function(){

    this.use('Mustache', 'ms');

    this.get('#/hello/:name/to/:friend', function(context){
        this.load('mypartial.ms')
        .then(function(partial){
            context.partials = {hello_friend: partial};
            context.name = context.params.name;
            context.friend = context.params.friend;

            context.partial('mytemplate.ms');
        });
    });
});
```

http://sammyjs.org/docs/api/0.7.4/all#Sammy.Handlebars
Note the version is 0.7.4